# Import class Actions does not working in ChromeDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Import class Actions does not working in ChromeDriver. My environment is **chromedriver 2.29 + selenium webdriver 3.4.0 + Chrome 58.0.3029.96 + Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)**. I press chord `Ctrl + Shift + O` (auto import in Eclipse) - it does not happen. If I insert string `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;` in code of Eclipse it marked as error.
Also I have tried run this class with **geckodriver 0.16.1 + selenium webdriver 3.4.0 + Firefox 53.0.2 + Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)** - result the same.

[image]

My Maven pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.andrey</groupId>
  <artifactId>Geckodriver</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Geckodriver testing</name>
  <description>Testing project for Udemy</description>

<properties>
    <selenium.version>3.4.0</selenium.version>
    <testng.version>6.9.9</testng.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
       <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
       <version>${testng.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How exactly are you adding selenium library to your project? If it's a jar (or jars) then tell where did you get it from. `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` class is a part of `selenium-api` dependency, but the same can be said about `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` interface, which is visible in your project.

Comment: @M. Czerwinski, I'm not adding library explicitly. I have created maven project, and in pom.xml file marked selenium.version 3.4.0. After that maven automaticly import all needed libraries in my project.

Comment: can you specify which maven dependency are you using exactly, is it [selenium-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.4.0)? Also, can you check the classes inside of your selenium dependency in eclipse? It should look like [this](http://imgur.com/a/DpONo), if it's different for you then please post a screenshot.

Comment: @M. Czerwinski, where I could see selenium dependency like your screenshot? I have this http://savepic.ru/13898220.png Also, I have edded  pom.xml file in first post.

Comment: @M. Czerwinski, http://savepic.ru/13949408.png The class Actions is absent.

Comment: It turned out, I had some mixed versions of selenium dependencies, after fixing and upgrading everything to version 3.4 I have `Actions` class in `selenium-remote-driver` ([screen](http://imgur.com/a/Xbg4H)), sorry for confusing comments before. It seems that your dependecies are correct, I don't really know why Eclipse has a problem with importing this class. You can try to compile your code outside of eclipse and to see if it's an eclipse-related problem.

Comment: You can't name your class `Actions` and create an object of `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` class. If you must then the right way of creating object is `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions builder = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(driver);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't name your class `Actions` and then create an object of the `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` class without qualification.

If you must then the right way of creating such an object is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions builder = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(driver);
```

Else just rename your `.java` file or `class`

from:

```
public class Actions {
    // code here
}
```

to:

```
public class MyCustomActions {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: thank you, this notation is work, but I think it is half-solution. Why the `webdriver 3.4.0` does not including class `Actions` ? What do you think about it? Recently I used to `webdriver 2.53.1` and class `Actions` was present in webdriver.

Comment: Can I adding this class in webdriver 3.4.0 artificially and use in my project short notation `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);`?

Comment: No you cannot. You have to rename your `class` or use the `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions builder = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(driver);`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have just guessed that I have name of my file.java the same as needed class `Actions`.  And I saw your answer with explanations.
Thank you, I am dummy)